# What's the difference between 雕像 and 雕塑?

Tags: mandarin, word

I've read the two sentences that used the word `雕像` and `雕塑`, respectively. However, I don't see what's the difference between the two words. When you look it up in a dictionary, both say "it is `statue`".

So is there anything that makes the one different from the other? I'm learning about Mandarin Chinese.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 像 character indicates that the sculpture is supposed to resemble a person, it's an "alike" or depiction of someone, 雕塑 may take more vague shapes, abstract sculptures, especially larger ones, etc., including persons of course.

Try using Google image search.

[First term: 雕像](https://www.google.hu/search?q=%E9%9B%95%E5%A1%91&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=xw9hVNeFC-qV7AbmnoGoBQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=673#tbm=isch&q=%E9%9B%95%E5%83%8F)
[Second term: 雕塑](https://www.google.hu/search?q=%E9%9B%95%E5%A1%91&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=xw9hVNeFC-qV7AbmnoGoBQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=673)

Comment: Oh, using Google image is a terrific idea. I appreciate your decomposition of the word, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A nuance reveals that 雕像 is a craft, 雕塑 is a art much more valuated.

Comment: Indeed. The works of ancient Greeks and Romans, or the masterpieces of the renaissance, though being sculptures of human figures, we never call them 雕像.

Answer (score 2):

(I am a Chinese, sorry for my English)

There is a band in China called (重塑雕像的權利 | Rebuilding The Rights Of Statues）

- 雕像：more emphasize it stands for something beyond the statue itself (like history, a kind of spirit, etc). 像 has the meaning 象征(represents). We will definitely call Mao Ze Dong's statue as 雕像，not 雕塑，cause we build statue not because it looks good, it reminds us something back in history.
- 雕塑：emphasize it's a piece of art. 塑 has the meaning it's made by a artist, not something normal people could easily do.

  But, normally, we use them quite interchangeability.

Answer (score 1):

雕像 is mostly for human and 雕塑 can be for anything.